# How to consider a related field in unique key in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a following django models:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class EntityProp(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey('Entity')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')
```

I want to make a unique key for `Entity` that includes `name` and related `EntityProp`. For example, I want two entities with the same name and different set of related `EntityProp` instances to be different. But I want to keep the same `Entity` if they have identical names and `EntityProp` instances. Is there an elegant way to do it in Django?

As a reserve way I can create an additional field in `Entity` called `props_hash` that contains a hash of the identifiers of all related instances, but it wouldn't be easy to support such structure, I think. So I believe there's a better way.

Comment: I think first of all you then want `entity` to be a `OneToOne` relation, right?

Comment: No, I need exactly one-to-many sort of relation.

Comment: Use `unique_together` on entity and key in EntityProp.

Comment: @thebjorn Show me how can I do it, please?

Comment: Like @kawadhiya21 does in his answer.

Comment: He created a unique key for `EntityProp`. But I need such key for `Entity`. I wrote it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class EntityProp(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey('Entity')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('key', 'entity')
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I need. Your code allows me to create as many records of `Entity` without related `EntityProp` as I like.